# In the development of the idea plugin, how to obtain the information of component dependencies introduced by the POM file in the current project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-plugin

I am developing an idea plugin, the requirement is to get the component dependency information introduced in the pom file of the current project, now I can get some information, when a component is introduced in the pom file without writing the version number, I can't get the version of the component, but in fact, in the project opened by idea, ctrl+ click on the component to enter the actual introduced version of the pom file. How can this situation be obtained?

```
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model model = reader.read(new FileReader(pomFilePath));
List<Dependency> dependencies = model.getDependencies();
for (Dependency dependency : dependencies) {
   String groupId = dependency.getGroupId();
   String artifactId = dependency.getArtifactId();
    String version = dependency.getVersion();
 }
```

Comment: You know that IntelliJ already has a lot of things to show dependency information etc. Can you explain more in detail what you mean by: `when a component is introduced in the pom file without writing the version number` ??

Comment: I solved it, I didn't use the maven plugin correctly